# Multiple drop-downs on a single container without interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a drop-down in a navigation bar, If I have one of them it's fine of course, but if I have multiple drop-downs It doesn't work as intended. If I click on the **first** drop-down, it opens, but then if I also click on the **second** drop-down after it opened, **both** of them opens **without** closing the other one that is not clicked, how do I implement such a functionality?

Here's my current code:

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-links">
        <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-link dropdown">
            <a href="#">
            Projects
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Shanary</a>
                <a href="#">Physics Solver</a>
                <a href="#">A simple blog</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-link dropdown">
            <a href="#">
            Projects
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Something else</a>
                <a href="#">Text Editor</a>
                <a href="#">A social Network</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #3A506B;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.navbar-links {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar-link,
.dropdown-content a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-link:hover,
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background: #3f5775;
}
.navbar-link a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    color: #5DD39E;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #3A506B;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #16302B;
    margin: 0px;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

and so far this is my JavaScript file:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

**Also here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytu5wt4b/).**

The problem is that, **both** of them open without closing the other one, here's an image of what is happening:

[image: Image of the situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through all targets to determine whether they are the current target or not and remove visibility

See snippet below

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible');
  var that = this;
  $('.dropdown').each(function() {
    if (that != this) {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-content').removeClass('visible');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #3A506B;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.navbar-links {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-link,
.dropdown-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-link:hover,
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: #3f5775;
}

.navbar-link a {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #5DD39E;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #3A506B;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #16302B;
  margin: 0px;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-links">
    <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-link dropdown">
      <a href="#">
            Projects
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Shanary</a>
        <a href="#">Physics Solver</a>
        <a href="#">A simple blog</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-link dropdown">
      <a href="#">
            Projects
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Something else</a>
        <a href="#">Text Editor</a>
        <a href="#">A social Network</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I ran the code snippet, It doesn't go as intended. You can't toggle the dropdowns, you can just switch between them. In other words, clicking on the dropdown toggle doesn't make them disappear. Which is what I want.

Comment: That will do it, Thanks for the answer. I will upvote and confirm it.